# map multiple functions to a single input

Tags: python, functional-programming

`map` is a builtin function that takes one function `func` and one or more iterables, and maps the function to each element in the iterables. I wrote the following function that does the reverse, but it feels like this is such a basic operation that someone must have done this before, and hopefully given a better name to this.

This appears to be a related question with a slightly different solution:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858735/apply-multiple-functions-with-map

```
from toolz import curry, compose


@curry
def fmap(funcs, x):
    return (f(x) for f in funcs)


cases = fmap([str.upper, str.lower, str.title])
tuple_of_cases = compose(tuple, cases)
strings = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
list(map(tuple_of_cases, strings))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, the code is not working as posted.
One has to add  `from toolz import curry, compose`.

Apart from this I like the solution and striving for more functional programming is probably always better. I also don't know a canonical solution for passing an argument to functions in python

Things I would definitely change:

1. I would not overdo the functional programming syntax. `list(map(...))` should be IMHO written as list comprehension. Even if one does not cast the result of `map` to a list, I find a generator comprehension to be more readable.

Small stuff:

2. `fmap` could get a docstring.
3. Type information with `mypy` etc. would be nice.
4. Perhaps `through` would be a better name for `fmap`. At least if one peeks to other languages. (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html)
5. Since `strings` is a constant, it could become uppercase.
6. Sometimes stuff does not need a separate name if functions are just concatenated and IMHO `tuple_of_cases` can go.

```
from toolz import curry, compose


@curry
def fmap(funcs, x):
    return (f(x) for f in funcs)

STRINGS = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
cases = compose(tuple, fmap([str.upper, str.lower, str.title]))

[cases(x) for x in STRINGS]
```

Comment: I fixed the missing import in my question. I couldn't really find a suitable name for the concept, but I like `through`, thanks for pointing me in that direction.